# Debugging Maven project with Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

The main project(Maven) I am working on, has multiple Gradle projects as its dependencies. I have all these Gradle dependencies projects imported as modules into my IntelliJ. When I debug my main project and attempt to step into a class that belongs to one of these Gradle dependencies, it takes me to the source class of the dependency (in the External Libraries) and not to the locally imported project.

What do I need to do so that the IDE will take me to the locally imported module rather than to the dependency that I cannot edit?

Comment: Have you tried:the `maven view` on the side bar (or `View->Tool Windows->Maven Projects`) select `Download Sources and Documentation`?